# Install Ubuntu from DVD alongside Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, multi-boot, installation-media

I'd like to install Ubuntu on my laptop SSD, so I can dual boot either Windows 10 or Ubuntu.

At [this guide](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html), it says to create an Ubuntu USB drive.

Can I put the Ubuntu install data on a DVD instead of USB?

I know I can boot from DVD.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I put the Ubuntu install data on a DVD instead of USB?

yes , you can burn it to a DVD. Right click on the Ubuntu ISO image and choose : **Burn disc image**.